# Calculate Probability that at least 1/4 stocks will be a total loss, given 40% of all stocks are at a total loss

Tags: probability, statistics

Homework Question -

Suppose 40% of the “risky” stocks will end up in a total loss.  However “risky” stocks provide high rewards, therefore you decide to invest in four “risky” stocks.  Assume that the performance of “risky” stocks are independent, the probability that at least one of them will become a total loss is closest to:

(a) 0.0256(b) 0.4(c) 0.7(d) 0.8704(e) 0.9744

Comment: Please compute the complementary probability (that all stocks will survive) and *type* the own thoughts.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The probability of at least one being a total loss is the probability of all of them being successful fails which is the probability of all of them failing at being total losses fails.

Comment: And the probability of X failing is $1 - P(X)$.....

Comment: @john doe so far i have tried computing the complementary probability and finding the probability that none of the stocks will fail

Comment: @fleablood could you please elaborate a bit more on what you mean? I am just a little confused

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: "so far i have tried computing the complementary probability and finding the probability that none of the stocks will fail"  That's the correct thing to do.  What did you get?  Why are you asking us if you figured it out yourself?  Or did you have trouble doing that? Where was the trouble?

Comment: @dan_fulea wouldn't the complementary probability of all stocks surviving be 0.25?

Comment: @fleablood because the question is asking to find the probability that at least one stock will fail.. not the probability that all stocks will survive, i can't figure out what the correct process is for questions like this

Comment: The probability that at least one stock failing is the probability complement of all stocks succeeding.

Comment: If you understand complements where is your trouble?  P(at least one failing)=P(not all succeeding)=1-P(all succeeding) =......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For at least one stock to be a total loss, is for it to not be the case that all stocks are not total losses.

If the probability of $X$ happening is $P(X)$ then the probability of $X$ not happening is $1-P(X)$.

So the probability of at least one stock being a total loss is $1 -$ the probability that all stocks are not total losses.

If the probability of $X$ is $P(X)$, then the probability of $X$ occurring $n$ times out of $n$ is $(P(X))^n$.

So the probability that all stocks are not total losses is $($the probability one stock is not a total losses$)^4$.

And repeating myself: If the probability of $X$ happening is $P(X)$ then the probability of $X$ not happening is $1-P(X)$.

So the probability that one stock is not a total loss is $1 -$ probability that a stock is a total loss.

And probability that a stock is a total lose is $0.4$.

Comment: the correct answer is 0.08704

Comment: according to the answer sheet

Comment: Well,...okay then.  P(one fails)=.4.  P(one succeed)=1-.4=.6.  and P(all succeed) = $0.6^4=0.1296$. And P(not all succeed=at least one fails) = 1- 0.1296 = 0.8704.